# How can I store the given responses(that were given as TextView) and use them again in giving response

Tags: java, android, arrays, storing-data

(**I am a beginner**)
I am making a decision maker app that gives responses randomly using a switch and changes the text of a TextView as output. What I want to do:

For example, if user asks "Should I post a question on stackoverflow?

taps OK

the app displays an answer randomly(say, Yes! you should do it.).

And next time when the user asks the same question I want the same response (**First time response should be random next time it should be same as given before**).I am using EditText for input.

I tried doing this with arrays but it does not work. If it is to be done by arrays please explain or give any other method for doing this...Thanks

Comment: Does the data have to persist beyond the current user session?

Comment: So you need a data structure that allows you to associate one object with another, and quickly find that value later on.  What data structure would that be?  And since you say you're a beginner-  if you haven't studied data structures yet, you really should be studying the fundamentals of programming before learning OS specific coding.

Comment: No,it should not @IvanWooll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was you I'd use a HashMap.

```
HashMap<String, String> mymap = new HashMap<String , String>();
```

Then you can save the question and answer like:

```
String question = "Should I post a question on stackoverflow?"
String answer = "Yes! you should do it"

mymap.put(question, answer);
```

And then when you want to retrieve the answer for this question you do it like:

```
mymap.get(question);
```

Edit:

The question in your HashMap is a key

To retrieve your answer you have to find it by the key(which is your question ).So instead of saying:

`mymap.get(answer);` you say `mymap.get(question);`

If you want to retrieve your question you probably have to write a method like:

```
public String getQuestion(String userQuetsion){

     if(mymap.keySet().contains(userQuestion))

          return userQuestion;

}
```

Comment: hi @new_to_coding I used HashMap but it does not work, here is my complete code if you could give it a look https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6InEecSXedCOHE5am91dFdOdVU/view?usp=sharing Thanks

Comment: your original code was working, there were some mistakes, rebuild the app and now it's working fine. Thanks for your help